# jvmkill is unable to kill the JVM in an image created by Paketo Java Buildpack

Tags: kubernetes, buildpack, paketo

I have a spring boot application v2.4.3 in a container created using the official spring boot gradle plugin which uses buildpakcs to do so.

One of the layers is jvmkill:

```sh
[creator]     Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:jvmkill'
```

which is perfectly fine and it is adding the jvm arg for jvmkill properly

```sh
Calculated JVM Memory Configuration: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx387804K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=148771K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M (Total Memory: 1G, Thread Count: 250, Loaded Class Count: 23852, Headroom: 0%)                                                                                                                                           
Adding 129 container CA certificates to JVM truststore                                                                                                                               
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -agentpath:/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jvmkill/jvmkill-1.16.0-RELEASE.so=printHeapHistogram=1 -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=2 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx387804K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=148771K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M                                                                                                                         
   .   ____          _            __ _ _                                                                                                                                              
  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \                                                                                                                                             
 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \                                                                                                                                            
  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )                                                                                                                                           
   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /                                                                                                                                            
  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/                                                                                                                                             
  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.3)
```

The app is running in Kubernetes (AWS EKS) but when I got an OOM

```sh
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

jvmkill kicks in, prints the heap dump and sends the kill signal

````sh
Heap                                                                                                                                                                                 
  def new generation   total 116736K, used 90606K [0x00000000e8400000, 0x00000000f02a0000, 0x00000000f02a0000)                                                                        
   eden space 103808K,  87% used [0x00000000e8400000, 0x00000000edc7bae0, 0x00000000ee960000)                                                                                         
   from space 12928K,   0% used [0x00000000ef600000, 0x00000000ef600000, 0x00000000f02a0000)                                                                                          
   to   space 12928K,   0% used [0x00000000ee960000, 0x00000000ee960000, 0x00000000ef600000)                                                                                          
  tenured generation   total 259456K, used 249951K [0x00000000f02a0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)                                                                       
    the space 259456K,  96% used [0x00000000f02a0000, 0x00000000ff6b7f18, 0x00000000ff6b8000, 0x0000000100000000)                                                                     
  Metaspace       used 74292K, capacity 76000K, committed 76824K, reserved 208160K                                                                                                    
   class space    used 8689K, capacity 9350K, committed 9600K, reserved 140576K                                                                                                       
 jvmkill killing current process                          ```
````

**but the jvm is never killed.**
Inspecting the container, I notice that the app runs with PID 1 which cannot be killed (or signaled) from inside the container.

```sh
cnb@myhost-6968d47f4b-2cnlj:/$ ps -fea
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
cnb          1     0  6 19:49 ?        00:00:54 java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
cnb        121     0  0 20:02 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
cnb        131   121  0 20:02 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -fea
```

since all this has been built by the java buildpack itself, I would expect that it is aware that PID 1 cannot be killed and launch the app differently to work properly.

Is there something that I am missing or need to configure for buildpack jvmkill to work out-of-the-box?

**Workarounds:**

1. If I were running the image directly with docker, I can use `docker run --init` to be able to signal the jvm process (my app runs with PID 7). Not valid for Kubernetes.

```sh
cnb          1  4.0  0.0   1120     4 ?        Ss   20:10   0:00 /sbin/docker-init -- java etc...
cnb          7  4.0  0.0  18372  1580 ?        S    20:10   0:00 java etc...
```

2. I can `shareProcessNamespace: true` in my k8s spec to have it running with PID other than 1, but would be hard to justify due to security compliance requirements.
3. I could just add the jvm flag `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` but then don't have the nice heap dump that jvmkill shows plus jvmkill thread creation failure coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Given the workaround mentioned in https://github.com/airlift/jvmkill#using-inside-docker-containers, you need something else to be pid 1. Kubernetes does not have the equiv of `--init` but if you include `tini` in your image, you can use it manually via the container command. You could also use `sh` similarly.

Also keep in mind this will only protect you from hitting the Java-level heap size limit. If you hit the actual container memory limit then your process is immediately terminated with no chance to catch it and do anything.

Comment: You could use https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/tini to get `tini` included in the image generated. You can also use the instructions here:https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/run-an-app/#user-provided-shell-process. Just copy & paste the start command generated by the builpacks (you can see it with `pack inspect <image>`) and use that command. By using the instructions I linked to, that should launch your process in a shell, which will make it not PID1. You can use those instructions to run with `tini` as well.